# Pandas Yahoo Datareader RemoteDataError when end date added

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

How come this code works on the yahoo data reader:

```
import pandas.io.data
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import datetime


df = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(['AAPL', 'GE', 'GOOG', 'IBM', 'KO', 'MSFT', 'PEP'],
                               start='1/1/2010',)['Adj Close']
```

But if I add an end date it gives me an error

```
df = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(['AAPL', 'GE', 'GOOG', 'IBM', 'KO', 'MSFT', 'PEP'],
                               start='1/1/2010',
                               end='1/1/2013')['Adj Close']
```

Error

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   21      
    get_data_yahoo  C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py 402     
    _get_data_from  C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py 355     
    _dl_mult_symbols    C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py 335     
RemoteDataError: No data fetched using '_get_hist_yahoo'
```

Pandas version '0.14.1-171-g08cf60a'

Python 3.3.3

Comment: Hmm. I get a different error on pandas 0.16.0 running python 3.4@ `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rs' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @EdChum Do you think I should open an issue on github?

Comment: I think so, before you do can you try today's date as in fact `end='27/3/2015'`, `'1/1/2015'`, `'1/1/2014'` all worked but `'1/1/2013'` did not so there may be some lack of error handling for when the end date is not a business day is my guess

Comment: @ccsv, this seems to be a bug. Please consider updating to the latest stable version `0.16.0` and update the error message. It's probably not helpful to open a bug report for an issue that might already have been fixed in the mean time.

Comment: works for me using 15.2 but using python 2 only. python3 errors with  `df_na = stocks.values()[0].copy()` for obvious reasons. `GOOG` also returns all NaN's.

Comment: @cel I was at the latest stable version 0.16 prior to asking  on stackoverflow and got the error. The update did not fix the problem

Comment: It also works using `python3.4` with `0.16` once you remove `GOOG`.

Comment: @EdChum I think it is a problem with the Bday calculations too. But I added an issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9739

Comment: @PadraicCunningham perhaps there is no Google trading on that day or it's missing, the question I guess is how this should be handled and whether the error message could be more informative

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Strange is it an issue with handling Nan? I tried `JNUG` and it did not work either.

Comment: @EdChum, the code works fine using python 2 but  GOOG always seems to return `NaN`  pre 2015

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that is odd. smells buggy to me

Comment: @EdChum, yes, python2 actually gives  a warning `SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'GOOG', replacing with NaN.` using 15.2 but using 0.16 and python3.4 I get the same error as you if I have a start date pre 2013

Comment: OK definitely something strange going on as the code now runs without error from 1-1-2010 to 1-1-2015 returning `[1258 rows x 7 columns]`

Comment: @ccsv, The issue seems to be when a Symbol returns all `NaN's` as `GOOG` seems to pre 2014, using the date above works fine as there is data returned for 2015 for `GOOG` but 2010-2013 returns all NAN's and errors.